# Is there a way to handle a double many-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a relationship between Foo, Bar, and Zork.

Zork and Foo are related, but for ease-of-use purposes they're managed by a relationship to 'Bar' instead, creating a many-to-many-to-many relationship.

(I. e. each Bar has many Foos, and each Foo can have many Bars.  Each Bar can be assigned to many Zorks, and each Zork can be assigned many Bars.  So Foo HABTM Bar, and Bar HABTM Zork)

Does active record have any support for this type of relationship?  I had to write a query by hand to handle the right-joins necessary to get the Foo's belonging to Zork, but the result is a tad bit fragile.  For example, the 'distcint id' portion of the query gets dropped anytime you .count the result, which is sub-optimal.  I can work around that by using count("Distinct id") instead, but that feels like a clumsy fix to the underlying problem -- and it breaks various helper methods I use to normalize my code for pagination.

Comment: Do you really mean a [`has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)?

Comment: @lurker almost, it's chained HABTM. There are 3 models and 2 HABTM links between them, so, models are linked through 2 extra tables: 5 DB tables in total.

Comment: I was originally (and probably superficially) thinking Foo HABTM Bar, and Bar HABTM Zork. Does the choice of words here (you say *has many* when discussing Foos and Bars, but you say *assigned many* when referring to Zorks and Bars) mean something specific functionally? You mention *for ease-of-use purposes* implying you want certain functionality. Perhaps you could elaborate on what kind of access to the data you ultimately want to perform efficiently.

Comment: @Lurker instead of 'Foo', 'Bar', and 'Zork', I probably should have said that I have many Foo objects, which are collected into Packages in a HABTM relationship.  Each Zork object can then be assigned one or more of those packages in yet another HABTM relationship.  I want to know what Foo objects a given Zork object has attaches through that double HABTM relationship.

Comment: By many Foo objects, you mean many different ActiveRecord classes then that are related in some way? I guess looking back at the question, the true nature of Foo, Bar, and Zork has not been revealed. :)

Comment: @lurker they're all ActiveRecord classes.  Each Foo record HABTM Package record, and each package record HABTM Zork records.

Comment: So if you define `Foo` AR with `has_and_belongs_to_many :packages`, `Zork` AR with `has_and_belongs_to_many :packages`, and `Package` AR with `has_and_belongs_to_many :foos` and `has_and_belongs_to_many :zorks`, in what way does that fail?

Comment: @Lurker the issue is I don't want an additional HABTM relationship between foo and zork.  The logic would be 'interesting' to manage, because every time a package was added or removed -- or a foo added or removed -- I'd have to completely rebuild the foo <-> zork relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be looking for the has_many :through relationship?
From the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

> The has_many :through association is also useful for setting up "shortcuts" through nested has_many associations. For example, if a document has many sections, and a section has many paragraphs, you may sometimes want to get a simple collection of all paragraphs in the document. You could set that up this way:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
  has_many :paragraphs, through: :sections
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document
  has_many :paragraphs
end

class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
end
```

> With through: :sections specified, Rails will now understand:

```
@document.paragraphs
```

Comment: There aren't many semantic differences between HABTM and HMT. While this can be solved using an extra HABTM relationship, mostly acting like a cache for the other two, it could easily become **huge** (sizes of existing join tables `a` and `b` multiplied in the worst case: `a*b`). No, it's more like querying existing data, one HABTM through another HABTM. The query should probably have multiple joins at once.

Comment: has_many :through doesn't work properly if the :through relationship is itself a many-to-many (HABTM).